# Hibernate not retrieving Many to Many relations

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have 2 tables with a many to many relationship, all tables are created in PostgreSQL using external scripts. I am struggling to get the full data in my data model objects. I am using Lombok and my entity classes look similar to this

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "TableA")
class TableA {
    @Id
    private int aId;
    private String aValue;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "TableAB",
        JoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="TableAId")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="TableBId")})
    private Set<TableB> tableBs = new HashSet<>();
}
```

and

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "TableB")
class TableB {
    @Id
    private int bId;
    private String bValue;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tableBs")
    private Set<TableA> tableAs;
}
```

When I run:

```
session.createQuery("FROM TableA a JOIN FETCH a.TableBs", TableA.class).list()
```

I get a list of TableA objects but tableBs in those objects is an empty Set. I have hibernate SQL turned on and I can see a query joining TableAB to TableB and if I run that query in the Intellij database console it returns the expected results.

I have tried also returning all TableB objects with a similar query, in the debugger that resolves the TableAs, but when not debugging or when running my application inside a Docker container I get nothing returned for TableAs.

I am using Java 19 with Hibernate 6.2.0-Final and version 42.6.0 of the PostgreSQL driver.

Any suggestions to how I can get TableA returned with TableB populated? TableB does have another relationship with a TableC which has One To Many relationships with a few other tables and I see queries for these in the logs as well, even though every relationship is marked as Lazy fetch.

EDIT: Fix typo

Comment: Is that a typo?   private in bId;. What is an in , is that a keyword or an API keyword, most id's usually are int or long and just interested.

Comment: Yes it is a typo. The code is not the real code but an example class. All of my code compiles and runs it is just the behaviour that is wrong.

Comment: I have a strong feeling that either there are no rows in TableB that reference the rows loaded from TableA, or you are getting a lazy load exception, but something in the code is swallowing it. Also please note that using `@Data` on entities will create all sorts of issues with Hibernate, please read the hibernate docs about equals and hashcode.

Comment: There is data in TableB that satisfies the query, in fact TableB has 4 rows and the one that is currently matching does sometimes have the tableAs Set populated, when I debug

Answer (score 0):

I solved is with the help of the comment from Augusto, it looks to be the @Data annotation that is the problem. I changed my classes to look like the following and it worked.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "TableA")
class TableA {
    @Id
    private int aId;
    private String aValue;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "TableAB",
        JoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="TableAId")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="TableBId")})
    private Set<TableB> tableBs = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        TableA tableA = (TableA) o;
        return aId == tableA.aId;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(aId);
    }
}
```

and

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "TableB")
class TableB {
    @Id
    private int bId;
    private String bValue;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tableBs")
    private Set<TableA> tableAs;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        TableB tableB = (TableB) o;
        return bId == tableB.bId;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(bId);
    }
}
```